# Why can't I build the SDK for Core Plot?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-plot

I'm having trouble getting Core Plot to work in my iPhone application. I followed these steps:

Five Steps to CorePlot

```
1. Copy the CorePlotSDK directory to ~/Library/SDKs/

2. Add to your project's .PCH file:

#import <CorePlot/CorePlot.h>

3. Open Project -> Edit Project Settings and for All Configurations:

 3a. Add to Additional SDKS: 

$HOME/Library/SDKs/CorePlotSDK/${PLATFORM_NAME}.sdk

 3b. Add to Other Linker Flags:

-ObjC -all_load -lCorePlot 

4. Add the QuartzCore framework to the project.

5. Add a CPGraph to your application.
```

And I try to compile the application and I get the following error:

```
error: There is no SDK with specified name or path '/Users/myusername/Documents/afolder/afolder/TestGA/Library/SDKs/CorePlotSDK/iphonesimulator.sdk
```

I've checked that this file location actually does exist by navigating to it in the finder. So why does xcode think its not there? I'm really having a hard time getting google code to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably got those instructions from the [Core-Plot Wiki](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingCorePlotInApplications), but there is also a step 6. Did you follow it? If it still doesn't work, did you see that this is experimental and may not work? Then try the **Static Library Install** instructions.

Also, this is no Google project, it's simply hosted on Google Code. ;)